# Application insight is not capturing the requests from Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, azure-application-insights

When we are manually accessing the application through browser, requests are captured in Application insight but when we are executing scripts in Jmeter , requests are not capturing in application insight. Please help

Comment: Please elaborate more on the approach you have tried to resolve the issue, also please provide the code you have added and the configuration ,library versions.

Comment: The Issue is - when we are manually accessing the application in our VDI through any browser, the monitoring team says the requests are getting captured in application insight but when the same functionality is being carried out though Performance script in JMeter tool, requests are not getting captured in application insight. The Performance script is working fine. What could be the reason for requests not capturing in application insight through JMeter scripts.

Comment: @PunyamPradhan, When you say "executing script in JMeter" have you also looked at the JMeter responses? Are those responses are in green? Even if they are green, did you check the response received is valid for each request? You are possibly missing something because of which JMeter is not able to trigger the request properly. Can you share the JMeter response, any error or warning in the Log Viewer, a screenshot of the elements used in the "Test Plan" to understand the script better

Answer (score 0):

I believe for doing that you have to simulate jmeter to act as a browser only, what i meant is in terms of cache manager, cookie manager, header manager, thread connection pool , you need to replicate the same behavior for jmeter too. For initial, you can try passing User-agent in the header manager. Check this article:

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser